# How do I merge/combine/add two arrays in SQL to form a new array?

Tags: sql, arrays, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a table that contains two columns which stores data in array format. For example, `column_1` contains values like [1,2,3,4] and `column_2` contains values like [5,6,7]. I want to combine these two in order to create a `column_3` who's value here would be the array [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]. The numbers will be unique, and the length of the arrays can be different.

Comment: I think [`array_cat`](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/array_cat.html) would do the job. [From their example](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/functions/array_cat.html#examples): `select array_cat(array1, array2) from array_demo;`

Comment: what database are you using

Comment: @JNevill some of the values for `column_1` or `column_2` are either a null or a an array with nothing in it: `[]`. I just got a `NULL result in a non-nullable column` error when I tried to use `array_cat`. Do you think I need to transform those `[]` into nulls instead? The snowflake docs imply that `array_cat` can support nulls

Comment: @Standin.Wolf I am using Snowflake SQL

Comment: That's curious. I don't have a snowflake system to test on so I'm hesitant to recommend a path forward. It does seem like a NULL would preferable to an empty array.

Comment: Could you post what you tried(with respect to the null values) and the resulting output. Just the post an example with null data, query using array_cat and the output of it

Answer (score 1):

does it work for you?

```
select array_cat(array_construct(NULL, 2), array_construct(3, 4));
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| ARRAY_CAT(ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(NULL, 2), ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(3, 4)) |
|------------------------------------------------------------|
| [                                                          |
|   undefined,                                               |
|   2,                                                       |
|   3,                                                       |
|   4                                                        |
| ]                                                          |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

But if you see such error:

```
select array_cat(NULL, array_construct(3, 4));
100072 (22000): NULL result in a non-nullable column
```

You can simply add:

```
select array_cat(IFNULL(NULL, array_construct()), array_construct(3, 4));
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
| ARRAY_CAT(IFNULL(NULL, ARRAY_CONSTRUCT()), ARRAY_CONSTRUCT(3, 4)) |
|-------------------------------------------------------------------|
| [                                                                 |
|   3,                                                              |
|   4                                                               |
| ]                                                                 |
+-------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 Row(s) produced. Time Elapsed: 1.241s
```

**Note:** Replace ARRAY_CONSTRUCT() to you column name.

Answer (score 0):

[ARRAY_CAT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_cat.html) is used to concatenate two arrays, removal of duplicates could be achieved by [ARRAY_DISTINCT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/array_distinct.html):

```
SELECT col1, col2,
       ARRAY_CAT(col1, col2),
       ARRAY_DISTINCT(ARRAY_CAT(col1, col2))
FROM tab;
```

For sample data:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE tab(col1 ARRAY, col2 ARRAY)
AS
SELECT '[1,2,3,4]', '[5,6,7]' UNION
SELECT '[1,2,2]',   '[1,3]'   UNION
SELECT '[NULL, 1]', '[NULL]';
```

Output:

[image]